# Stop page from scroll when changing page contents using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am toggling a div using jquery. when this div appears on page my browser scroll bar goes to top, even i am on last of my page. can you help me to stop this scroll where it is even more and more divs appears on page using jquery

i shall be thank full

Comment: Post your code and we might be able to help ... my crystal ball is in for repair at the moment ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the link which is being clicked that controls the div toggle is set as `href="#"`. If this is the case, add `preventDefault()` to the jQuery `click` event handler to stop the link behaviour from making the page scroll to the top.

```
$("#myLink").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // toggle your div
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to place all the divs that scroll inside another div that has a fixed height.